# Modern alternative for frameset layout

Tags: asp.net, html, web-applications

Here's my mainpage layout:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

</HEAD>
<FRAMESET>
    <FRAMESET>
        <FRAME name="menu"  src=<%=menu%> >
        <FRAME src=<%=bottom%> >
    </FRAMESET>
    <FRAMESET>
        <FRAME  src=<%=tittle%>  >
        <FRAME name="center"  src=<%=center%>>
    </FRAMESET>
</FRAMESET>
```

Since this page was build 10 years ago and html5 does not support framesets anymore I'd like to modernize my layout.

Which would be the alternative nowadays?

Comment: framesets where most of the time used when there was no scripting language available on the server, to make it easier to separate menu form content. or to reduce loading time. if you want to reduce loading time, you can use ajax request. so a current replacement for framests is using composing/publishing framework or serverside mvc framework.

Comment: It's just for layout purposes.

Comment: then look at the answer of Blender and at [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a alternative per se. "Just" rewrite your whole page using modern HTML&CSS. If you have no idea on how to do that I would suggest getting a book or two (on HTML5&CSS3) and work your way from there. Sorry but there really isn't anything more specific we can answer you here.

Answer (score 1):

Do some reading about html5. Descide if your site should be responsive (that is shall it resize to fit various sized clients such as both desktop browsers and mobile browsers well).
If it should be responsive do some reading about that.

My "personal/general" advice:

I think you should get rid of the frames. If you are to use asp.net (not MVC), you could put the parts that are shared between pages in a master page. Menus should be located in a `<nav>` element and the navigation menu should be built using `<ul> / <li>` elements and styled to look like you want.

There are lots of examples on the web. For example take a look at http://www.initializr.com/ where you can download a template for a new website in the "new style".

Comment: Personal opinion: I would also try to get rid of asp.net and use MVC if possible. asp.net was built trying to be a "web approximate" of visual basic desktop applications with approximately the same form, control and event metaphor. I don't think that metaphor is relevant any more.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            ...
        </header>

        <div id="content">
            ...
        </div>

        <footer>
            ...
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just dissect some existing sites. There's no recipe that works for every case.